# php ini vs json and halt compiler hack

Tags: php, json, ini

I am debating on using either a `configuration.ini` or `config.json` for my administration dashboard I am designing. I like that `ini` is more for configuration purposes but with todays interest in JSON it seems more logical for the configurations be designed with json in mind.

Question here is should I use json for sure? And secondly I have this hack currently on my `configuration.ini` file which prevents the file being seen publicly.

```
;<?php exit(); __halt_compiler();
; //to stop script execution if not used in our best interest!
; //remember this format

  //ini stuff

;?>
```

I was wondering if I could use this with the json file as well? I haven't tested it just because I didn't want nothing strange completely screwing everything up.As well as a good description as to why this works, now I know this won't work specifically with JSON since the `;` is `ini` based commenting so could it be transformed to `//` or `/**/` for json?

For interest purposes this is currently my `admin__autoload.php` page

```
set_include_path(dirname($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]));   
$ini = parse_ini_file("configurations.ini",true);
foreach($ini as $section=>$values) {
    foreach($values as $key=>$value )   {
        define("__".strtoupper($key)."__",$value);
    }
}

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        if(!file_exists(get_include_path(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .__ADMIN__."classes/{$class}.php")) {
            echo get_include_path(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .__ADMIN__."classes/{$class}.php does not exist";
        } else {
            include_once get_include_path(). DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .__ADMIN__."classes/{$class}.php";
        }
});
```

`__ADMIN__` was created with the foreach loop from my ini file.

Comment: You couldn't use it with JSON without preprocessing (or a JSOL extractor). And it would only work for the `.ini` if PHP actually handled that extension. Otherwise masking it per `.htaccess` or locating it above the document root is the more common safeguard. -- Why would you want JSON or INI anyway? It's not like there are generic or user-friendly configuration editors anyway. Why not just a simple php script with arrays or something?

Comment: For simple minded users who will be accessing these files. I know that using the arrays is much faster and to us easier than making a JSON file and then doing `json_decode` but like I said either INI or JSON are my options. They are cleaner for users to read through compared to others. I know PHP arrays are just like JSON except minor differences. But yeah hope you understand what I am working with here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're asking two different questions here.

1. Which configuration format will best suite my needs
2. How do I prevent my configuration files from being accessed by the public

The answer to 2 is easy. Don't put your configuration files in your public document root.

As far as choosing between INI or JSON, it's rather subjective without understanding the use case very clearly.

INI is more expressive for the reader but harder to parse. JSON is quite portable as a serialization format, but harder to read as a human.

So if you're manually editing the configuration file a lot, it makes sense to go with INI as its slightly disambiguated than JSON. If you're doing the editing through an autonomous process or one that otherwise requires portability across disparate systems, JSON may be more convenient.

A third alternative is [YAML](http://yaml.org/), which is a good middle ground between the human-readable aspect of INI, and the portability of JSON.

Comment: I won't use YAML from the processing PHP needs in comparison to Json or ini . It'll be both be able to be accessed through editing in admin dashboard but a real developer can easily go in and fix anything if need be. I understand the hierarchy but I just am always a paranoid nut when it comes to security haha. But if someone really wanted to hack they would. I guess it really boils down to what I want. I should look at the speeds of ini processing vs Json processing in php.

Comment: Well, the security part of your question is thoroughly answered by just not making sensitive files available under the public docroot. As far as performance is concerned it's quite likely JSON parsing will be more expensive than `parse_ini` in PHP, but that does depend on which version of PHP, which JSON parser implementation you're using, and the overall structure of your JSON. INI isn't expensive to parse computationally, it's a flat structure. If this is really your biggest performance determent and the basis of your format choice you aren't thinking hard enough (*caching* comes to mind)

Comment: Maybe not lol I get brain farts after hours. But I'm using php 5.5 I believe. And it's not a very deep Json structure maybe three levels deepest. I'll do a quick mktime trial. Thanks looks like I'll have to do some more thinking. As of now I still have ini as the primary config

Comment: Is it possible that you can perhaps rephrase your question more concisely to something like "*Configuration format: INI vs JSON vs YAML. What are the performance and convenience characteristics of each? What are the trade offs and when to use them?*" At least this way the question will be more useful to someone else trying to make the same decision in the future and people can provide far more object answers. I must admit *halt compiler hack* and *php ini vs json* parts of your question aren't exactly clear as to what you're asking.

Comment: That is to say if the basis of your question is truly focused on figuring out the performance and convenience pros and cons of each format for your config file, then you should try to make that pretty obvious in your question and you'll likely get better answers. Not to mention help the community at large for when someone else is searching for the same problem.

Comment: I will. I was tired and headed to bed when I wrote this thanks man

Comment: After years I know I've accepted the answer lol. Had more time under my belt. Thank you for your in depth explanations and understanding.